# PHP Form Textarea Mysql add <br/> after enter is pressed

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have a form.

```
<form method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="home_box01_About_Header" placeholder="" value="<?php echo $row['home_box01_About_Header']; ?>"></input>
    <br/><br/>
    <textarea id="text" name="home_box01_About_Content" rows="25" cols="100"><?php echo $row['home_box01_About_Content']; ?></textarea>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save!" />
</form>
```

Which displays the current data in Mysql table and let me change it from the Form.

I have alot of text to include in the Textarea, so when I press the Enter key on my keyboard, I want to include an `<br/>` automatically.

( I just pressed enter 2 times now, and the line above is free - an good example. )

( Free above and under)

And again.

How can I do this using PHP?

[Image Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wANQu.png)

Comment: What did you expect would happen if you pressed enter twice? I'm not sure I understand exactly what you want.

Comment: Why not just convert newlines to `<br>` on display?

Answer (score 1):

Try `nl2br`.

This inserts HTML line breaks before all newlines in a string.

In your example as you are storing data in a database, you'll need  `mysql_real_escape_string()` to escape the line breaks.

Example:

```
<?php echo nl2br($row['home_box01_About_Content']); ?>
```

Comment: This nearly does the work. It does include the <br /> but I have to update it twice for the Output to include it.